# Displaying toast message in a text View android

Tags: android, android-toast

I am trying to display toast message in my textView but it needs to update every second in order to display all package names (every second) but I'm getting an error in my code saying **"Cannot refer to a non-final variable pnum inside an inner class defined in a different method"**

in the line "msgto.setText("optimized " +
                     procInfos.get(pnum).processName);"

```
        // display all package names
        ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (int pnum = 0; pnum < procInfos.size(); pnum++) {
            if ((procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("android")
                    || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("system")
                    || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("huawei")
                    || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("adil")) {

            } else {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    //do your thing here
                     TextView msgto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.optimizedapp);
                     msgto.setText("optimized " +
                     procInfos.get(pnum).processName);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
            }
        }
    }
```

i tried putting the whole code in my thread but getting this error in log cat (after 2 sec which is the thread time)

```
06-30 06:35:15.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5281): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12964
06-30 06:35:15.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5281): Process: com.example.xtremenetbooster, PID: 5281
06-30 06:35:15.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5281): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

    // THREAD

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                // do your thing here
                // display all package names
                ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(
                                getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager
                        .getRunningAppProcesses();
                for (int pnum = 0; pnum < procInfos.size(); pnum++) {
                    if ((procInfos.get(pnum)).processName
                            .contains("android")
                            || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName
                                    .contains("system")
                            || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName
                                    .contains("huawei")
                            || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName
                                    .contains("adil")) {
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        // "system apps",
                        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        TextView msgto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.optimizedapp);
                        msgto.setText("optimized "
                                + procInfos.get(pnum).processName);
                    }
                }
                //
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
} // THREAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from trying to access `pnum` @ `msgto.setText("optimized " + procInfos.get(pnum).processName);` when pnum is clearly defined inside your `for` loop

[see me](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a new final int inside the loop:

```
        // display all package names
        ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (int pnum = 0; pnum < procInfos.size(); pnum++) {
            final int finalpnum = pnum;
            if ((procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("android")
                    || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("system")
                    || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("huawei")
                    || (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("adil")) {

            } else {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    //do your thing here
                     TextView msgto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.optimizedapp);
                     msgto.setText("optimized " +
                     procInfos.get(finalpnum).processName);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't do anything, it just closes the app after 3 sec without a force close message and the text also doesn't change :/

Comment: its not working because it tells me to put a "final" before starting the for loop